# Distribution of a pdf-related random variable $Y=f(X)$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable having cdf $F_{X}$ and pdf $f(x)$ expressed as in the following:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, & x \in [0, 1] \\
\frac{1}{x}, & x \in [1, e^{1/2}]
\end{cases}
$$

I have to study the distribution of the variable $Y=f(X)$:

$$
Y=
\begin{cases}
X, & X\in[0,1]\\
\frac{1}{X}, & X\in [1, e^{1/2}]
\end{cases}
$$

My idea to find the cdf $F_{Y}$ is the following:

- if $X$ is in $[0, 1]$, then $Y$ has its values $y$ in the interval $[0,1]$, so:
  $$
  F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq y)=\int_{0}^{y}x\, dx=\frac{y^2}{2};
  $$
- if $X$ is in $[1, e^{1/2}]$, then $Y$ has its values $y$ in the interval $[e^{-1/2}, 1]$, so:
  \begin{align}
  F_{Y}(y)&=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)|_{y \in[0,1]}+\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)|_{y \in[1, e^{1/2}]} \\
  &=\mathbb{P}(X\leq y)|_{y \in[0,1]}+\mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{X}\leq y)|_{y \in[1, e^{1/2}]}=\mathbb{P}(X\leq y)+\mathbb{P}\Bigl(X\geq \frac{1}{y}\Bigr)=\int_{0}^{y}x\,dx+1-\int_{e^{1/2}}^{1/y}\frac{1}{x}\,dx \\
  &=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+log{y}
  \end{align}

So the pdf $f_{Y}$ of the random variable $Y$ is:

$$
f_{Y}(y)=\frac{dF_{Y}}{dy}(y)=
\begin{cases}
y, & y \in [0, e^{-1/2}] \\
y+\frac{1}{y}, & y \in [e^{-1/2}, 1]\\
0, & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Is this right?

Comment: The result looks reasonable to me, though the justification for the particular split might be clearer

Comment: @Henry How could I justificate the split in a clearer way? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No, the way you write the answer is not correct. You cannot split the computation into the two cases because $X$ is a r.v., not a constant.
$$P(Y \leq y)=P(X \in [0,1], X \leq y)+P(X\in (1,e^{1/2}], \frac  1 X \leq y)$$ $$=P(X \in [0,1], X \leq y)+P(X\in (1,e^{1/2}], X \geq \frac 1 y).$$ I will let you do the computations now.

Comment: The computations look correct to me

Comment: @Henry You cannot write $F_Y(y)=\frac {y^{2}} 2$ if $X \in [0,1]$. That is non-sense.

Comment: Indeed, though I would not call that a computation. What is correct is that $F_Y(y)=\frac {y^{2}} 2$  and $f_Y(y)=y$ if $y \in \left( 0, e^{-1/2}\right)$, while  $F_Y(y)=\frac12+ \frac {y^{2}} 2+ \log y$  and $f_Y(y)=y+\frac1y$ if $y \in \left(e^{-1/2},1\right)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'll not write that $F_{Y}(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}$ if $X \in [0, 1]$, but what I'll say is the following:

(1) if $X \in [0, 1]$, then it's true that $Y=X$, so $y \in [0,1]$;
(2) $X \in (1, e^{1/2}]$, then it's true that $Y=\frac{1}{X}$, so $y \in (e^{-1/2}, 1]$.

So my conclusion is the one written in the last comment by Henry.

Do you say that this is not correct and that the cdf $F_{Y}$ can't be split in two parts?

Comment: @met.91 Now it is right. I was only commenting on the way you wrote the answer, not the final result.